# For a compact group $G$ and any finite-dimensional complex representation $(\pi,V)$, how to show that $V$ admits an invariant inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, inner-products

To demonstrate that an inner product $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$ on $V$ is invariant, one need to check
$$\langle\pi(g)v,\pi(g)w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle.$$
For an arbitrary inner product $\langle\langle\ ,\ \rangle\rangle$, consider the following inner product:
$$\langle v,w\rangle=\int_G\langle\langle\pi(g)v,\pi(g)w\rangle\rangle\textrm{d}g.$$
Now I try to show that $\langle\pi(h)v,\pi(h)w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$ as
$$\begin{aligned}
 \langle\pi(h)v,\pi(h)w\rangle&=\int_G\langle\langle\pi(g)\pi(h) v,\pi(g)\pi(h) w\rangle\rangle\textrm{d}g & \\
&= \int_G\langle\langle\pi(gh) v,\pi(gh) w\rangle\rangle\textrm{d}g & \\
&= \cdots= \langle v,w\rangle,& \\
\end{aligned}$$
but I find it hard to check that
$$\int_G\langle\langle\pi(gh) v,\pi(gh) w\rangle\rangle\textrm{d}g=\int_G\langle\langle\pi(g)v,\pi(g)w\rangle\rangle\textrm{d}g.$$
Could you please provide me with some hints?

Comment: Abusing notation slightly, use invariance of the Haar measure to replace $\mathrm{d}g$ by $\mathrm{d}(gh)$

Comment: As @user10354138 indicates, the key step is to use that $\int_G$ isn't an arbitrary measure on $G$, but the Haar measure, so satisfies $\int_G \phi(g) \mathrm{d}g = \int_G \phi(gh) \mathrm{d}g$ for any $h \in G$ and (integrable) $\phi : G \to \mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Haar measure, we have $\textrm{d}g=\textrm{d}(gh)$. Then it follows that
$$∫_G⟨⟨π(gh)v,π(gh)w⟩⟩\textrm{d}g=\int_G⟨⟨π(g)v,π(g)w⟩⟩\textrm{d}(gh^{-1})=∫_G⟨⟨π(g)v,π(g)w⟩⟩\textrm{d}g$$
by $g\mapsto gh^{-1}$.